# Resetting Button States in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am creating a Phonegap & JQuery mobile application.  I have some buttons, and on navigating in the app, if you go back to the menu screen you see them still selected (in active state) or else in hover state.

Is it possible to reset the state once the user goes back to the menu screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, you need to remove its ui-btn-active class.

Example:

```
$("#button").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
```

Do it in pagebeforeshow event:

```
$('#page').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $("#button").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
});
```

Comment: would the active state be applied though if the user clicks on the button again?

Comment: Yes it will be applied again. jQM is a little bit buggy with button states after page transition has occurred.

Comment: Can the same be applied for ui-btn-hover?  removing the class on pagebeforeshow?

Comment: Yes it can, remove it if it is applied.

Comment: I would put this in a separate JS file if it's going to be used site-wide.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement: It is possible to set, and therefore grab, the active-button class from jQM dynamically (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11413195/241244)), which means this will work if you or someone down the line decides to change it.

```
$(document).delegate("#page-id", "pagebeforeshow", function(){
    var activeClass = $.mobile.activeBtnClass;
    $(this).find("."+activeClass).removeClass(activeClass);
});
```