# Trouble with button and ajax post

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, button

I have two problems that I would like to ask about. The webapp should send "somedata" via POST (ajax), then put the returned data from the server into the div. I use jQuery, jQuery mobile and phonegap. So the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="searchingform">
    <form method="post" id="sform">
        <input type="text" name="group" id="somedata" value="" placeholder="Enter SOMEDATA that will be posted to the server"/>
        <div id="buttoncover">
            <input type="button" id="loadbut" value="Load" data-mini="true" onClick="sendPost();">
        </div>
    </form> 
</div>
<div id="cnt"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

And here is JS code:

```
function sendPost() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'http://thepagethatanswers.com',
        data:{'group':$('[name=somedata]').val()},
        response:'html',
        success:function (data) {
            $('#cnt').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
        $('#output').html('Error');
        }
    });
};
```

So the user fills the form, presses the button, it is sent to the server, and the answer is filled into `#cnt` div. Genegally it works BUT:

1.After pressing the button it remains pressed. It works, but has the appearance of pressed button. jQuery makes that

```
<div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-disabled="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-up-b" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Load</span>
    </span>
    <input type="button" id="loadbut" value="Load" data-mini="true" onclick="sendPost();return true;" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-disabled="false">
</div>
```

from

```
<input type="button" id="loadbut" value="Load" data-mini="true" onClick="sendPost();">
```

I tried to `.removeclass('ui-btn-active')` that appears, but it has no effect. I tried to totally rewrite the button, it made it look like inactive, but then it didn't wand to appear like pushed one. I just need it to be able to show normal behavior in terms of appearance.

2.There is need to resend the 'somedata' from the form to server in order to update the information and load it in the `#cnt`. And here is my second issue: untill the 'somedata' in the form is not changed to some other value the POST does not happen. Example: we put "1" in the input, press the button, get the answer, it t fills the `#cnt` - that's fine. Then we press the button again in order to update the info and nothing happens. Change the value of input, press the button - it updates the `#cnt` according to a new value of input. I need it to be able to press the button many times and it will send the same value and get the right `#cnt`. The server code is quite complicated, but in fact it just gets the `$_POST['somedata']` and then returns html back.

UPD: Solution to refresh of ajax request: I added to sent data one more variable and now it looks like this:

```
data:{'group':$('[name=group]').val(),tstamp: new Date().getTime()}
```

So the request is sent every time and the `data` refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  You can always redefine this class using e.g. inline style. Or see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507099/how-do-you-remove-a-buttons-active-state-with-jquery-mobile).

2) Set cache to false according to [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).