# "Unclicking" all jQuery mobile buttons after onClick

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870331/jquery-mobile-button-staying-pressed) about jQuery mobile buttons staying pressed after they are clicked.

I received a helpful snippet which removes this property:

```
('#login').find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-focus');
```

But I'm sick of placing it all around my code.

How can I write a global functions which removes the class `ui-btn-active ui-focus` from any jQuery mobile button that is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

This script will help you:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.ui-btn', function() {
        $('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-focus');
    });
});
```